# In Unity Dash, when I type 'o' is not visible while 'O' is visible. How to repair?

Tags: unity, 14.04, hud

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit, Unity-3D HUD.

Lowercase 'o' is not visible in HUD. But uppercase 'O' is visible.

Anyway search results are correct.

[image]

In Unity Dash, when I type 'o' is not visible while 'O' is visible. How to repair?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Is this only dash, or `alt+F2` run dialog too?

Comment: In both (Dash, Run), the same bug remains.

Comment: Not happening in Gnome shell. Definitely a bug IMHO (a strange one, indeed).